# How to create a Flash Movieclip via a web interface?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Forgive me if this is not the correct place to ask such a question.

Basically, I am looking for a way to allow someone to easily (at least, easier then diving into Flash) create a basic Flash animation (movieclip) with some placed image assets and text, all via a web interface.

I was thinking along the lines of using jQuery to allow drag and drop assets, of which you'd "record" the co-ordinates and relay that to Flash somehow to create the SWF file.

Or would it be better to create a tool in Flash (surely making operations easier) and then have some kind of "save" button to render out the SWF?

I'm totally open to suggestions.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If you really need to produce a stand-alone SWF file (and not just a config file for you own "player"), I would probably do it like this;

1) Create your editor in whatever system you feel like (flash, jquery etc).

2) Build a config file in the client. This is used, together with all the resources the user added, to play back the animation.

3) Upload said assets and config file to your web server.

4) Use the flex compiler (on the server) to produce the resulting SWF, combining your player with generated AS3 which embeds the uploaded resources as needed, to make it available to the player.

5) Give the user a download link for the newly generated SWF file.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any swf compiler available for Flash (actionescript). You may create a swf that allows users to create an animation, save it as a home-made vector format, and then replay it. But I don't believe you can create and independant swf file with only the created animation in it.

Just think about a player in Flash, and a format that the player will read (xml, json, name it...). You can either generate the input with jQuery or Flash, and then feed it into your player to display it. You will eventually need two files.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently [this library](https://github.com/claus/as3swf) allows you to compile SWFs at runtime. I haven't used it myself (yet) and don't know how stable or flexible it is, but it appears to be what you're looking for. I'd recommend giving it a spin and seeing if it's sufficient.

I'm not exactly sure how it saves the file, so you might run into security problems since it's a web application. Hopefully it should be OK though.